# How can I draw directly to the PictureBox.Image property (if possible)?

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, bitmap, touch

I have been using the Windows Touch Scratchpad Sample in C# (MTScratchpadWMTouchCS) example located at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd940546(v=vs.85).aspx and it works beautifully.

What I would like to do, is set the Form.BackgroundImage to a BMP file, which works fine at the moment.

Next, I would like to be able to 'scribble' over the form using a touch device - also working without issues at the moment.

Then, I to use a Button to use 'DrawImage' to place another BMP file (or Bitmap object) of an 'Emoji' (for example) onto the form, and be able to retreive it using the Form.Image property. Also working fine.

Lastly, and this is where my issue is - I need to be able to 'grab' the Form.Image property and be able to save it to a file. This almost works, in that it grabs the 'emoji' but it does not grab the 'scribble'

So looking at the Example linked above, it appears that it does not 'draw' to the Image property of the form. Is there a way I can acheive this? Graphics have always eluded me.

Comment: You are not drawing to the image your are drawing to the Form.  To draw to the image you will need to use Graphics.CopFromImage

Comment: Do you mean Graphics.CopyFromImage? If so, do you have an example, because I cannot find that function documented anywhere.
What you sare saying regarding drawing to the form though, is spot on - instead of drawing it to the form, I need to draw it to the image - just need to work out how :)

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.fromimage(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: If you want to paint images on top of images, then you need to do exactly that. You can't use UI controls to get the desired effect if you want to save the result as image file afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, that's really a lot of questions so you should deal with them one at a time.  But to address the general aspects of your problem:

Don't work directly on the form.  Add controls to the form that you can interact with.  For instance, I would add a `Panel` and make it take up the entire client area (`Fill` mode).  Then, I would add controls to that `Panel`, such as a `PictureBox`.  You can either subscribe to the controls' `Paint` events, or even inherit your own control and override the `Paint` event for full control.  Depends on how much you need to get a hold on.